# Creating an page on web app where an admin can confirm users in AWS Userpool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm currently building out a server-less web application on AWS that allows end users to register for accounts.

My registration process (to create users) is making use of aws-amplify for JavaScript to send requests to AWS Cognito from the front-end. There is absolutely no custom backend I'm running on my localhost; I've done this all from a simple Create React App and this part is working. When a user registers, he/she pops up on the AWS Cognito dashboard as shown below. Notice the `UNCONFIRMED` account status.

[image]

I am interested in having a page on my web app where a user with some kind of **admin** privileges can log in and see a list of `UNCONFIRMED` users and be able to either accept them or reject them, much like the AWS Cognito dashboard.

This is where I struggle to understand how to accomplish this while maintaining security.

I know that aws-amplify doesn't offer the API I need but the original [JavaScript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminConfirmSignUp-property) for AWS offers `adminConfirmSignUp` which confirms user registration as an admin without using a confirmation code.

What does it mean when it states "confirms user registration as an **admin**"? What is the definition of an **admin** here? Is it as simple as a user in UserPool that's under some group I create that contains some AWS Administrator Role?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the AWS Javascript SDK and `adminConfimSignUp` method are the solution you are looking for.

The definition of admin here is that it is an admin user that confirms the user in the userpool; you're the admin and you're confirming the user... As the administrator you're confirming the user.

Comment: Thank you for that.

However, how do I make a normal user an admin?